# Is it possible to initialise more than one array at a time?

Tags: python, arrays, append

I have this array:

```
A = array([[450.,   0., 509., 395.,   0.,   0., 449.],
          [490.,   0., 572., 357.,   0.,   0., 489.],
          [568.,   0., 506., 227.,   0.,   0., 567.]])
A.shape = (3, 7)
```

I want to create 3 distinct empty arrays with names that progressively increase and append each row of the original one.

```
example: 
array1 = [450.,   0., 509., 395.,   0.,   0., 449.]
array2 = [490.,   0., 572., 357.,   0.,   0., 489.]
array3 = [568.,   0., 506., 227.,   0.,   0., 567.]
```

this is just an example, consider that I'm supposed to work with an initial array with many more rows than this one. So, let's say that I need to create as many arrays as the number of rows of my original one and append each row in order. Hope I was clear.

update:

I have a swc file with 500 rows with are similar to the one of the array A.
With a for loop I have to find the rows that in the 1st column have the same value of one of the 6th column of the array A. If this condition is met that column should be appended to the appropriate array.

example:

in my swc file I have this 3 rows that meet my condition:

```
[449.   0. 510. 394.   0.   0. 448.]
[489.   0. 571. 357.   0.   0. 488.]
[567.   0. 505. 228.   0.   0. 566.]
```

so I need to append them to the appropriate array.
Let's suppose that I have manually created my arrays:

```
array1 = [450.,   0., 509., 395.,   0.,   0., 449.]
array2 = [490.,   0., 572., 357.,   0.,   0., 489.]
array3 = [568.,   0., 506., 227.,   0.,   0., 567.],
```

I would expect this:

```
array1 = [450.,   0., 509., 395.,   0.,   0., 449.], [449.   0. 510. 394.   0.   0. 448.]
    array2 = [490.,   0., 572., 357.,   0.,   0., 489.], [489.   0. 571. 357.   0.   0. 488.]
    array3 = [568.,   0., 506., 227.,   0.,   0., 567.], [567.   0. 505. 228.   0.   0. 566.]
```

Comment: its not clear what you are asking ... you could do `array1,array2,array3 = A` for the specific example given

Comment: I don't want to do it one by one...I could do it, but if I have an initial array with 100 row, should I do array1, array2,array3...array100 = A?

Comment: You would simply do `array1 = A[0,:]`, `array2 = A[1,:]`. The issue is that with a lot of rows, manually assigning each array will become very tedious so we don't actually do the above. Instead, we either just subset (ie `A[i,:]`) where `i` is the desired row *or* we can store them in a dictionary, for example: `aDict={}; for i in range(a.shape[0]): aDict[i] = A[i,:]`. but...i fail to see the purpose since it's easier to just subset

Comment: Nothing *advisable* will create new names `array1`, `array2`, etc for you. You can create a *list* of arrays with `rows = [array(row) for row in A]`, if that's all you need.

Comment: This would need to dynamically create variables "array4", "array5",... This is not recommended. Instead you could use a list or just keep the array as it is.

Comment: @GeneBurinsky I need to create 3 distinct ones since later on I need to append many more data to them..

Comment: @ludovica can you show us how you'd be appending such data or what you'd like to append? You can add rows/columns to arrays if needed. So for example, if you generate another array `B` of shape (3,7) then you can append it to `A` with `np.concatenate((A,B),axis=0)` which will give you a matrix shaped 6x7

Comment: @GeneBurinsky I updated my question..I could do it manually creating 3 arrays, but the problem is that I have to create many more than just 3

Answer (score 0):

## The Short Answer

The following 2-liner will give you the the desired result

```
cond = A[:,0]-1 == A[:,6] # compare columns 1 and 7, find ones that match (well, with -1...check details)
np.concatenate((A[cond,:],A[cond,:]),axis=0) # append rows that meet the condition to respective rows
```

## The Details and Explanation

This can be fairly efficiently done in the following way (note, you said the 1st and 6th columns must match but in the question, you show results where the value in the 7th column is -1 of the value in the 1st and the value of the 2nd column is equal to the 6th column. It isn't clear what you want so I'll assume it's the former (doesn't matter, really, it can easily be updated)).

### Find rows that meet the condition

```
# find which rows satisfy your condition in your swc array
# compare columns 1 and 7 (note, Python indexes from 0, not 1)
cond = A[:,0]-1==A[:,6] # can also do A[:,1]==A[:,5] ..you get the point

# return the rows that meet the condition of equal column values within rows
A[cond,:] # this is just for illustrative purposes, not really needed for the task
```

### Append rows that meet the condition to rows that meet the condition

For the final part appending part, it isn't exactly clear from your question how you'd like to append.

**Row-wise** appending: Since your desired result is not actually a valid assignment

```
array1 = [450.,   0., 509., 395.,   0.,   0., 449.], [449.   0. 510. 394.   0.   0. 448.]
```

I can only assume you actually meant

```
array1 = np.array([[450.,   0., 509., 395.,   0.,   0., 449.], [449. ,  0., 510. ,394.  , 0.  , 0. ,448.]])
```

which would mean that `array1` is a 2x7 array so the desired appending is **row-wise**. (column-wise would give you a 1x14 array instead)

Assuming my inference is right then you just concatenate the matrix as such:

```
# append (row-wise, as your operation of appending to `array1` would suggest) to relevant subset
B = np.concatenate((A[cond,:],A[cond,:]),axis=0)
B.shape
```

So the `B` matrix is of shape 6x7 (3x7 original plus 3x7 copy), as desired.